# Declare variables with Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, global-variables

I'm just wondering if it's fine to declare variables with JSON format?

For example, do this:

```
$(function(){
    var global = {
        varA : 'This is a global variable from global.varA ~!',
        varB : 'This is a global variable from global.varB ~!'
    };

    alert(global.varA);
    alert(global.varB);
});
```

Instead of this:

```
$(function(){
    var globalVarA = 'This is a global variable from globalVarA ~!',
        globalVarB = 'This is a global variable from globalVarA ~!';

    alert(globalVarA);
});
```

- The reason why I want to do this is that, It would be easier to look for when I work on a really long JS file. And anything starts with **`global.`** I know it is a global variable.
- Is it a good practice?
- Is there anything I need to put into considerations?

Comment: It's not json, it's just a javascript object.

Comment: And you are not creating global variables at all. The first is completely valid JS, so why not just do that? What it does is create a *local* variable `global` whose value is an object. *edit:* Oh you are asking whether it's "fine". Yes it is ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not JSON format, it's just normal javascript object literal.

Second, since it's valid syntax, you could do this, and this is normal practice to put the variables in a namespace (*through there's no namespace concept in javascript*).

If you want to make `global` be **global**, then you could set it to be a property of the global object `window`:

```
$(function(){
    var global = {
        varA : 'This is a global variable from global.varA ~!',
        varB : 'This is a global variable from global.varB ~!'
    };
    window['global'] = global;    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "new variables" are actually properties of an object literal. They are not variables, nor do they have global scope. However,  I don't think it's the worst way to define "references to values". You're using an object as an *associative array*, which is A-OK.